# Compare objects in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

What I'm trying to achieve is that if a Post contains comments, it should display the comments. I tried the angular.equals, which either doesn't work or I am not familiar on how to use it right?

Here's the Controller for both Post and Comment.

```
var PostController = function ($scope, $location, Post, Comment) {
    $scope.search = function () {
        Post.query({
            offset: $scope.offset,
            limit: $scope.limit
        },
        function (data) {
            $scope.more = data.length === 20;
            $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(data);
        });
    };

    $scope.searchComments = function () {
        Comment.query({
        },
        function (data) {
            $scope.comments = data;
        });
    };

    $scope.showComment = function () {
        angular.equals(Post, Comment);
    }
}
```

And here's from the view:

```
<ul class="posts">
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <div class="post-info">
            <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
                <div class="right-section">
                    <div class="edit-post-button right"><a href="#/edit">Edit</a></div>
                    <span class="reputation right">{{post.reputation}}</span>
                </div>

        </div>

        <br />



        <div class="post-box">
            <p>
                {{post.content}}
            </p>
        </div> 
        <br />

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="comment in comments" ng-show="showComment()">
                {{comment.content}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Maybe this could be done in the back-end? I am not sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to *filter* the comments to a particaular `post`.  As you have said in comments, the `Comment` resource has a `pid` that ties it to a particular post.

The best way to accomplish the filtering is with an [angular filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

In this way, you don't need to compare anything with `equals`, you can just filter the comments in the markup:

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="comment in comments | filter:{ pid: post.id }">
            {{comment.content}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Because all posts get all comments then?

Comment: You are showing all comments in `$scope.comments`, how do you intend to filter them to a single post?

Comment: That's the question mate, how would I go further?

Comment: Is there a `postId` on each comment?

Comment: OK, I've made a significant edit.  Let me know if it makes sense.  I've assumed that the `post` has an `id` property that would be the same as the `comment.pid`.

Comment: Tweaked it a bit since you couldn't know what it was called exactly , but it solved it in the end! Cheers mate! :)